# Issue with form submission , validation and AJAX request - "unknown status" error (Laravel)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm encountering an issue with form submission and an AJAX request on my web application. When I submit the form using AJAX, I'm getting an "unknown status" error in the console, and the form data doesn't seem to be submitted correctly.

Here's a brief overview of my setup:

I have a form with several input fields for capturing family member details (name, date of birth, Aadhar number, relationship, etc.).
I'm using JavaScript/jQuery to handle the form submission via AJAX.
On the server-side (PHP), I have a do_add_family function that receives the form data and saves it to the database using the EmployeeFamily model.
I have already checked the following:

The form fields are correctly named and have the required attributes.
The JavaScript code for handling the form submission seems to be working, as there are no apparent errors in the browser console.
The server-side code appears to be fine, as it creates the EmployeeFamily records without errors.
However, despite these checks, I'm still encountering the "unknown status" error and the form data is not being submitted successfully.

Herer is the preview of my code :
HTML -

```php
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="step2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="step2-tab">
   @php
   $memberNumber = 1;
   @endphp
   <script>
      var memberCounter = 1;
      
      function addMember() {
          // Clone the last family member row
          var lastMember = document.querySelector('.family-member:last-of-type');
          var newMember = lastMember.cloneNode(true);
      
          // Increment the member counter and update the radio button ID and name attributes
          memberCounter++;
          var radioBtn = newMember.querySelector('.family-member-radio');
          radioBtn.setAttribute('id', 'nominee-' + memberCounter);
          radioBtn.setAttribute('name', 'nominee'); // Set the name attribute to "nominee"
          radioBtn.setAttribute('value', 'nominee-' + memberCounter); // Set the value attribute to "nominee-x"
      
          // Change the button text to "Remove this member"
          var addButton = newMember.querySelector('.add-member-btn');
          addButton.textContent = 'Remove this member';
          addButton.classList.remove('btn-warning');
          addButton.classList.add('btn-danger');
          addButton.setAttribute('onclick', 'removeMember(this)');
      
          // Reset the values of the input fields
          var inputs = newMember.querySelectorAll('input, select');
          inputs.forEach(function (input) {
              if (input.type === 'radio') {
                  input.checked = false; // Uncheck the radio button
              } else {
                  input.value = ''; // Clear the input field value
              }
          });
      
          // Append the new member row to the family members container
          var container = document.getElementById('family-members-container');
          container.appendChild(newMember);
      }
      
      function removeMember(button) {
          var memberRow = button.closest('.family-member');
          memberRow.remove();
      }
   </script>
   @if(Auth::guard('company')->check())
   <form action="{{ route('company.do_add_family') }}" id="family" method="post">
      @elseif(Auth::guard('admin')->check())
   <form action="{{ route('admin.do_add_family') }}" id="family" method="post">
      @elseif(Auth::guard('member')->check())
   <form action="{{ route('member.do_add_family') }}" id="family" method="post">
      @endif
      @csrf
      <div id="family-members-container">
         <div class="row align-items-center family-member text-center">
            <!-- <input type="hidden" id="employeeIdInput" name="id"> -->
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="193">
            <div class="col-2">
               <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                     <input class="form-check-input family-member-radio" type="radio" name="nominee"
                        value="nominee-{{ $memberNumber }}">
                     <label class="form-check-label">My Nominee</label>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
               <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name[]" placeholder="Name" required>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
               <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="date" class="form-control" name="dob[]" placeholder="Date of Birth" required>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
               <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="aadhar[]" placeholder="Aadhar Number" required
                     min="14" max="14" oninput="formatAadharNo(this)">
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
               <div class="form-group">
                  <select class="form-control" name="relation[]" required>
                     <option value="">Select Relation</option>
                     <option value="Mother">Mother</option>
                     <option value="Father">Father</option>
                     <option value="Spouse">Spouse</option>
                     <option value="Sister">Sister</option>
                     <option value="Brother">Brother</option>
                     <option value="Daughter">Daughter</option>
                     <option value="Son">Son</option>
                  </select>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
               <div class="form-group">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary add-member-btn" onclick="addMember()">Add a new
                  member</button>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row justify-content-end text-center">
         <div class="col-auto">
            <button class="btn btn-info previous">Previous</button>
         </div>
         <div class="col-auto">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success family_next" name="submit">Save As Draft / Next</button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </form>
</div>
```

Script

```js
$('.family_next').click(function () {
// Get the form action URL
    var familyformActionUrl = $('#family').attr('action');
// Get the input field values
    var formData = {
        nominee: $('input[name="nominee"]:checked').val(),
        name: $('input[name="name[]"]').map(function() {
            return this.value;
        }).get(),
        dob: $('input[name="dob[]"]').map(function() {
            return this.value;
        }).get(),
        aadhar: $('input[name="aadhar[]"]').map(function() {
            return this.value;
        }).get(),
        relation: $('select[name="relation[]"]').map(function() {
            return this.value;
        }).get()
    };
// Submit the form using AJAX
    $.ajax({
        url: familyformActionUrl,
        method: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        success: function (response) {
// Handle the success response
            console.log(response);
// Show the next tab
            activateNextTab();
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
// Handle the error response
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
});
```

Server Side Code

```php
public function do_add_family(Request $request)
    {
        $id = $request->input('id');
        $dob = $request->input('dob');
        $aadhar = $request->input('aadhar');
        $relation = $request->input('relation');
        $nominee = $request->input('nominee');
        $name = $request->input('name');
        
        $success = true; // Initialize the success variable
        
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($dob); $i++) {
            $is_nominee = ($nominee === "nominee-" . ($i+1)) ? "yes" : "no";
            $data = [
                'employee_id' => $id,
                'name' => $name[$i],
                'date_of_birth' => $dob[$i],
                'aadhar_number' => $aadhar[$i],
                'relationship' => $relation[$i],
                'nominee' => $is_nominee
            ];
            
            // Try to create the EmployeeFamily record
            $created = EmployeeFamily::create($data);
            
            if (!$created) {
                $success = false; // Set success to false if creation fails
                break; // Exit the loop if an error occurs
            }
        }

        if ($success) {
            return response()->json(['success' => 'Family members added successfully.', 'id' => $id]);
        } else {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'An error occurred while adding family members.', 'id' => $id]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Unknown status` is a 419 error, which for Laravel means missing CSRF token.

Comment: I have added the @csrf token

Comment: Since you're using AJAX to submit the data and building your own formData instead of serializing the form,, adding `@csrf` to your form won't do anything. You probably should pass [X-CSRF-TOKEN](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token) in your ajax headers.

Comment: I tried it after adding this am getting 500 error.
$.ajax({
                            url: familyformActionUrl,
                            method: 'POST',
                            headers: {
                            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                        },

Comment: A 500 error is an Internal Server Error. Check both your server error logs and your laravel logs for more information.